# sklearn OneHotEncoder returns wrong size shape data

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am making a pipeline with sklearn to handle my dataset, when trying to use OneHotEncoder (to transform not-numeric attributes into numeric ones) as one of pipeline's step - it **returns the wrong shape** size array.

The shape of original dataset is (8693, 14) and final dataset returned using pipeline must have the same size. Generally if I don't use OneHotEncoder in pipeline - it returns normal shape size array, but when I add it - shape is ruined and it's wrong.

[image]

Can you help please? Already tried OneHotEncoder parameters, 'toarray' method, 'resize' method and they do not solve the problem.

Comment: That's what OHE is supposed to do.  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) creates one column per category, to map a categorical/string column to a number you can use [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) instead.